# Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded During a setTimeout Call

Tags: javascript, html, time

I'm trying to call my function every 4 seconds so it will increment a number live. For some reason I keep getting errors. Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Recycle Counter</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function rand(from, to)
    {
       return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from); // Generates random number
    }   

    var num = rand(10000, 100000);

    function getNum() // Gets triggered by page load so innerHTML works
    {
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = num + 7;
        setTimeOut(getNum(), 4000);
    }   
</script>
</head>
<body onload="getNum()">
    <div id="counter">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You realize that your function getNum() will get stuck in an endless recursive loop right?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Inside `getNum`, you're directly invoking the `getNum` function, causing the stack to exhaust. Replace the function call `getNum()` with the function reference `getNum`:

```
function getNum() // Gets triggered by page load so innerHTML works
{
    num += 7;     // Increase and assign variable
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = num;
    setTimeout(getNum, 4000);   // <-- The correct way
}
```

Link to documentation of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).

Comment: Ha! yeah that got rid of the error but that didn't make it start incrementing. Ima keep at it thanks!

Comment: Now it increases. You have to assign the `num` variable.

Comment: What if a `getNum` function takes arguments?

Comment: @parsecer You can add them like this: `setTimeout(getNum, 4000, arg1, arg2, arg3, etc)`

Answer (score 10):

The problem is your call to `setTimeout` is invoking `getNum` instead of scheduling it for execution.  This leads to infinite recursion and a stack overflow.  Try the following instead

```
setTimeout(getNum, 4000);
```

Answer (score 4):

`setTimeOut` should be `setTimeout`