# Javascript Stack overflow while running setTimeout method + passing variable

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, timeout, settimeout

I know what the problem I am experiencing is, I am just having a hard time finding a work around. I was wondering if anyone had experienced something like this, and what kinda of solution they implemented.

I have a list system with pending repairs, and I want repairs that are late to blink black and red. It's possible that there are multiple repairs in this list that are late.

here is my function:

```
function setblink(id) {
   var elm = document.getElementById(id);
    if (elm.color == "red"){
        elm.color = "black";
    }
    else{
        elm.color = "red";
    }
    setTimeout(setblink(id),500);
}
```

I have an array of "id's" for the items that need to be blinking called repsToBlink.

I get the set blink intervals running for each of these repairs by running the following code, which puts them in a recursive loop.

```
for(var x in repsToBlink){
setTimeout(setblink(repsToBlink[x]),500);
}
```

How can I get this code doing the same thing, without causing a stack overflow?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to do this with pure CSS try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Krr7m/). More info at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_animations). You will need to add more vendor specific prefixes to get it to work with more browsers and it won't work in older browsers.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of a `setTimeout()` for each element. Using a list instead: http://jsfiddle.net/HdCbt/

Comment: Dup of [Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731840/), [Why does calling setTimeout with parenthesis not start a new callstack?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058996/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your setTimeout from

```
setTimeout(setblink(id),500);
```

to:

```
setTimeout(function() { setblink(id) },500);
```

`setTimeout()` expects a function to be passed as parameter, whereas you are passing the result of the function.

Answer (score 2):

`setblink(id)` calls the function immediately. A stack overflow is a symptom of immediate, rather than delayed, execution since `setTimeout` schedules execution for later so the future invocation won't get pushed on the current call stack.

Since `setblink` takes an argument, wrap it in a [nullary](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/zeroaryfunc.html) anonymous function for [lazy evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

```
function setblink(id) {
   var elm = document.getElementById(id);
    if (elm.color == "red"){
        elm.color = "black";
    }
    else{
        elm.color = "red";
    }
    setTimeout(function () {setblink(id)},500);
}

for (var x in repsToBlink){
    (function (id) {
        setTimeout(function () {setblink(id)},500);
    })(repsToBlink[x]);
}
```

The code calls for more improvements.

If `repsToBlink` is an array, you should [loop over the integer indices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/90527) of `repsToBlink` (`for (...;...;...)`), not the properties ([`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#arrayNote)). However, if instead you were to use an object with the ids an indices (rather than values), `for ... in` would be appropriate.

The above fires a separate timer for each `id` (which could overwhelm the browser). By moving the loop to a function, which becomes the only function to be scheduled, only a single timer is required.

Since you're running a function periodically, `setInterval` is more appropriate.

Whenever you remove and id from `repsToBlink`, check whether there are any remaining; if not, cancel the interval.

```
(function () {
    var repsToBlink, repCount=0, blinkInterval;

    function startBlinking(ids) {
        addRepsToBlink(ids);
        if (! blinkInterval) {
            blinkInterval = setTimeout(blinkAll, 500);
        }
    }

    function addRepsToBlink(ids) {
        for (var i=0; i<ids.length; ++i) {
            addRep(ids[i]);
        }
    }

    function addRep(id) {
        if (! id in repsToBlink) {
            ++repCount;
            repsToBlink[ids[i]] = true;
        }
    }

    function removeRep(id) {
        if (id in repsToBlink) {
            delete repsToBlink[id];
            --repCount;
            if (!repCount) {
                clearInterval(blinkInterval);
                blinkInterval=0;
            }
        }
    }

    function blinkAll() {
        for (id in repsToBlink) {
            blink(id);
        }
    }

    function blink(id) {
        var elm = document.getElementById(id);
        if (elm.color == "red"){
            elm.color = "black";
        } else {
            elm.color = "red";
        }
    }

    window.startBlinking = startBlinking;
    window.addRepsToBlink = addRepsToBlink;
    window.addRep = addRep;
    window.removeRep = removeRep;
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `setTimeout` is being called in a global context. That, and you're instantly calling the function.

The interpreter, when it gets to this code:

`setTimeout(setblink(id),500);`

is calling the `setblink` function immediately, assuming that that function's return value is what the timeout is supposed to call. This causes a stack overflow, because that is a recursive function.

To fix, this, wrap the function that setTimeout is to call inside a `function(){}`.