# Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded During a Recursive function with setTimeout Call

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to execute the following function using [Fidler](https://jsfiddle.net/) but still not getting the expected results. Basically, I have a deeply nested array that I would like to iterate through and get the sum. I have gone through the [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731840/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-during-a-settimeout-call) but still can't see what I'm doing wrong.

The code is as follows:

EDIT

Thanks for the responses but the reason I was trying to use setTimeout() because the elements are many. See the full code below which I'm trying in [Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/)

```
const ElementsCount = 10000; //If I change this to 1000 its fine, when 10000 or more it gives error

const createDeeplyNestedArray = (ElementsCount) => {
      let retval = [1];
      for (let i = 0; i < ElementsCount - 1; i++) {
        retval = [1, retval];
      }
      return retval;
    };

const deeplyNestedArray = createDeeplyNestedArray(ElementsCount);
let sum = 0;

function sumArray(deeplyNestedArray) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (const entry of deeplyNestedArray) {
    if (typeof entry === 'number') {
      sum += entry;
    } else {
      sum += sumArray(entry);
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
var res = sumArray(deeplyNestedArray);
console.log(res); //Expected 10000 but getting maximum call stack exceeded
```

Comment: Why do you need a setTimeout?

Comment: Does it have to be a recursive function? You could use `.flat(Infinity)` on the array, and then just iterate over that flattened array to sum the elements.

Comment: `return sum;` doesn't wait for the timeout, hence the result

Comment: deeplyNestedArray array can have 100,000 elements, I tried .flat(infinity) it giving maximum call stack exceeded

Comment: @Andy The only advantage of a recursive function is that it only iterates through the array once instead of multiple times like `Array.prototype.flat()` does, but I agree that in this case this is probably micro-optimisation and it's more readable to use `.flat(Infinity).reduce((acc, sum) => acc + sum, 0)`

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to find the precise line?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use setTimeout at all. In fact, there is an easier way to perform the sum:

1. Start `sum` with 0
2. Iterate through a received array (from the first positional argument).

   - If the entry is a number, add it to the sum
   - If the entry is an array, recurse but adding the return function itself to the sum

In code it will look something like this:

```
function sumArray(arr) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (const entry of arr) {
    if (typeof entry === 'number') {
      sum += entry;
    } else {
      sum += sumArray(entry);
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

See proof-of-concept below, with optimisation using ternary operator:

```js
const deeplyNestedArray = [1, [1, [1, [1, [1, [1, [1, [1, [1, [1]]]]]]]]]]

function sumArray(arr) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (const entry of arr) {
    sum += typeof entry === 'number' ? entry : sumArray(entry);
  }
  return sum;
}

const result = sumArray(deeplyNestedArray);
console.log("sum", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic answer: `setTimeout` is not waiting for calculation of `sum`,
so after calling of `sumArray` - action is done inly one time. And after this - you are receiving answer where `sum` is `1`.

```js
const deeplyNestedArray = [1, [1, [1, [1, [1, [1, [1, [1, [1, [1]]]]]]]]]]
var sum = 0;

function sumArray() {
   let element = deeplyNestedArray.shift();

    if(element){
        if (Number.isInteger(+element)) sum += +element;
        else deeplyNestedArray.push(...element);

        sumArray();
    }
  return sum;
}

const result = sumArray();
console.log("sum",result);
```